# In a CNN neural network model i am trying to fit my data to fit.model () but it's showing error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

Here,

```
X_train = 75% of my cancer image data, which has 3 classes.
Y_train = images are labeled as [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2] 
X_test = 25% image of my cancer dataset 

results = model.fit(X_train,Y_train, X_test, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=6, epochs=5,
```

##################################

But getting this errors,
which should I pass into model.fit()

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-c29910126b61> in <module>()
  5         tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='logs')]
  6 
----> 7 results = model.fit(X_train,Y_train, X_test, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=6, 
epochs=5, callbacks=callbacks)
  8 
  9 ####################################

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     62     filtered_tb = None
     63     try:
---> 64       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)

TypeError: fit() got multiple values for argument 'batch_size'
```

Answer (score 0):

The fit method doesn't know what to do with X_test, the validation data needs to be passed explicitly

```
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=2,
    # We pass some validation for
    # monitoring validation loss and metrics
    # at the end of each epoch
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)
```

It's good practice to go through the documentation once or twice: [Training and evaluation with the built-in methods](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `validation_split` to create your validation set, it is easier in my experience, if done when you create your data generator.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.1)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
```

You then use your data generator, either with `flow`, or `flow_from_directory`, using your train data.

```
train_iter = train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=6, subset="training")
val_iter = train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=6, subset="validation")
test_iter = test_datagen.flow(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=6, shuffle=False)
```

Then `.fit` your model using `train_iter` as x-input and `val_iter` as input for `validation_data`.

```
model.fit(train_iter, steps_per_epoch=len(train_iter), validation_data=val_iter, validation_steps=len(val_iter), epochs=5, shuffle=True)
```

Then use `test_iter` to evaluate/predict.

```
model.evaluate(test_iter, steps=len(test_iter))
model.predict(test_iter, steps=len(test_iter))
```

Comment: train_iter = train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=6, subset="training")
val_iter = train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=6, subset="validation")
test_iter = test_datagen.flow(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=6, shuffle=False)

After running this i am still getting value error

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-4d09eb3570be> in <module>()
----> 1 train_iter = train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=6, subset="training")
      2 val_iter = train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=6, subset="validation")
      3 test_iter = test_datagen.flow(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=6, shuffle=False)

Comment: Here is my colab link to see the code 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hT7v4iW5zZ-Kd5mMrTrQwhOfI9XJuaqq?usp=sharing

Comment: It tells you what the issue is: `ValueError: Training and validation subsets have different number of classes after the split. If your numpy arrays are sorted by the label, you might want to shuffle them.`

Comment: @Shan Looking at your code, you're not actually verifying that you're splitting your dataset into training and test sets with equal classes, and there's no way for anyone but you to check if the training data has matching classes to the test set. This will also mirror with the validation set since it's created from the training set. I suggest using `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split; X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_images, train_labels, test_size=, random_state=)`

Comment: Can you pls check why  am I  still getting this error ?

 https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hT7v4iW5zZ-Kd5mMrTrQwhOfI9XJuaqq?usp=sharing#scrollTo=D81NTvbEww_F

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-4d09eb3570be> in <module>()
----> 1 train_iter = train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=6, subset="training")
      2 val_iter = train_datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=6, subset="validation")
      3 test_iter = test_datagen.flow(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=6, shuffle=False)

Comment: It tells you the issue: `ValueError: "x" (images tensor) and "y" (labels) should have the same length. Found: x.shape = (128, 128, 3), y.shape = (33,)` Your classes and labels don't match (or what you're passing as classes and labels). Looks like you're loading a single image to train against 33 labels when there probably should be a lot more images. Idk because I'm not familiar with that dataset and not really running your code.

Comment: If your labels are correct, you're missing 32 images (or all 33). Your images dataset should have shape `x, h, w, c` where `x, h, w, c = numOfImages, height, width, channels`. If your images are correct, your labels should be one since it's a label per image.

Comment: Unless you're using 128x1d images, then you're 95 labels short.